# Angular 2 can't stop ngSubmit from propagating

Tags: angular

stopPropagation() should prevent the callback `doSearch()` from firing when form is invalid.

```
<form 
  [dirtyFieldsOnSubmit]="form"
  (ngSubmit)="doSearch()"
  #form="ngForm"></form>
```

Directive code:

```
import {Directive, Input, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({ selector: '[dirtyFieldsOnSubmit]' })
export class DirtyFieldsOnSubmitDirective {
  @Input('dirtyFieldsOnSubmit') form: NgForm;
  constructor() {
  }
  @HostListener('submit', ['$event'])
  onSubmit(event) {
    if(!this.form.valid) {
      for (var i in this.form.controls) {
        this.form.controls[i].markAsDirty();
      }
      //event.stopPropagation() not working
    }
  }
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: onSubmit() {}   // try after removing event

Comment: Could you explain that a bit better?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return false` at the end of your function. That stops the propagation.